# Publishing wsdl java M2E plugin execution not covered

Tags: maven-2, wsdl, wsdl2java

I have written a WSDL and I want to generate java classes.

I use the [cxf-codegen-plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) for maven2, but I get the following validation error in Eclipse:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.2.7:wsdl2java (execution:
>   generate-sources, phase: generate-sources).

Can anybody help me to resolve this? Or propose another solution?

Comment: This link should be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009916/hyperjaxb-and-apache-cxf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message sounds like it is coming from the maven eclipse integration (m2e). If the build works from the command line but not from within eclipse then maybe this [article on the eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered) can help you to configure eclipse.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6372575/139595) shows the solution for a similar problem with another maven plugin.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#execute_plugin_goal adding this section into my pom.xml sovled my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this snippet to your pom.xml (from the link published by @Jörn Horstmann):

```
<pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.3.3,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

The more important lines are:

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.3.3,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                        </goals>
```

So, you have to ensure what version of CXF are you using...
Hope this can help...

Answer (score 0):

Change the plugin version to this especific. After, Run Maven Update Project, and finally Run Maven generate-sources

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7.10</version>
```

Best regards,

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer is incomprehensible.